# Hello to everybody, Can somebody advise me good localization plugin or extension?

Tags: sencha-touch

I'm using sencha touch 2 and i want to add localization functional to my mobile app. I spent  2 days to look for localization plugin and i found [Ux.locale.Manager](https://github.com/mitchellsimoens/Ux.locale.Manager). But it's not suitable to my project.

Answer (score 0):

This app has quite a good implementation of using Localisation, check it out, posted in the Sencha Touch 2 Examples area of the forum:

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?256010-Anthologia-Mobile

Direct links to project:

More info: http://html5.mxnet.it/anthologia/mobile/

Demo: http://html5.mxnet.it/demos/anthologia/mobile/

Code: https://github.com/mxnet/AnthologiaMobile

In the localisation info section it says this:

**Localization**

The file index.html of the application must contains the link to the preferred localization:

```
<script src="resources/config/locale-en_US.js"></script>
```

You can edit each localized string of the included file:

```
<script src="resources/config/locale-en_US.js"></script>)
```

The contents of the file is self-explanatory, but we will improve the related documentation.

:-)